# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'function'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Hi I am new react and new to redux.

I am trying to fetch data from my firebase firestore to the client side .However when I am trying to do this . I am getting an error like so:

[image]

I am trying to get the elements in my app.js and am creating the store there.

here is my App.js:

```
const DEFAULT_REDUCER = (initstate, action) => {
  return {
    key: "HELLOW WORLD",
  };
};

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    DEFAULT: DEFAULT_REDUCER,
    categories: categoryReducer,
  })
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Authenticated>
            <Dashboard />
          </Authenticated>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Authenticated nonAuthenticated={true}>
            <Login />
          </Authenticated>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" render={() => "404 Not Found!"} />
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My categoryReducer.js:

```
const initialState = null;

const categoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOAD_CATEGORIES":
      state = action.payload;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
};

export default categoryReducer;
```

my categoryActions.js

```
export const loadCategories = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    firestore
      .collection("CATEGORIES")
      .orderBy("index")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        let categories = [];
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            categories.push(doc.data());
          });
          dispatch({ type: "LOAD_CATEGORIES", payload: categories });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

my HomeFragment.js

```
export class HomeFragment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 0,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.categories === null) {
      console.log("test1");
      this.props.loadCategories();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container maxWidth="md" fixed>
        <AppBar position="static" color="white">
          <Tabs
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
            aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
          >
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <BannerSlider
          Images={[{ image: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" }]}
        />
        <HorizontalScroller />
        <StripAdView />
        <GridView />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export const CategoryTab = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Avatar
        alt="Remy Sharp"
        variant="square"
        src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
      />
      <Typography variant="body2">Title</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    categories: state.categories,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadCategories: () => dispatch(loadCategories()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeFragment);
```

What should I do to make it work

Comment: You are missing a middleware that handles asynchronous actions. See the react-redux documentation. https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware BTW if you integrate redux-toolkit you get the asynchronous thunk middleware included. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/

Comment: How do I add it to the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing middleware to handle asynchronous actions. Redux recommends using [Thunks](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).

[Using Thunk Middleware for Async Actions](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#example-using-thunk-middleware-for-async-actions)

1. Import `applyMiddleware` from `redux`
2. Import `thunk` from `redux-thunk`
3. Create your store with the correct configuration.

   ```
   import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
   import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

   const store = createStore(
     combineReducers({
       DEFAULT: DEFAULT_REDUCER,
       categories: categoryReducer,
     }),
     applyMiddleware(thunk), // <-- add the Thunk middleware
   );
   ```